# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of null.jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Getting the error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'find' of null." in the console. Underlining this line of code containing the error: 
`if ($sResults.find("product").length > 0)`

Anyone have any idea why this is happening. Im a beginner so any adivce would help. Thanks.

```
if ($sResults.find("product").length > 0) {
  // We have some search results
  // The products are in $sResults


} else {
  // We don't have any results
  // Hide the table
  $("#mainBody").find("table").hide();
  $("#mainBody").append("<h3>There are no search results. </h3>");
}
```

Comment: what is $sResults? is this a variable? or are you trying to select a CSS property with an id or class called sResults

Comment: @ManishMallavarapu Yes $sResults is a variable.

Answer (score 0):

$sResults is null, for whatever reason. Perhaps you are hitting an API or otherwise dynamically getting that info and nothing is being returned, or perhaps you have that info available locally and it is not being passed correctly - either way, you are calling .find on null and that is the issue. It may be okay, if fetching the info dynamically, to have no results, right? If it's not - that is one of two problems because *your first (and current
) problem is that your code is breaking*. It's breaking because you are not protecting it by checking to see if $sResults HAS a value before you run .find()

For a more precise answer on WHY you are getting a null value, we would need more code ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
if ($sResults && $sResults.find("product").length > 0) {
  // We have some search results
  // The products are in $sResults


} else {
  // We don't have any results
  // Hide the table
  $("#mainBody").find("table").hide();
  $("#mainBody").append("<h3>There are no search results. </h3>");
}
```